# QT in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: qt

I want to use QT 5 with Visual Studio . I got it set up but only option is QT 5 64bit version with the QT add-in for VS 2012 .

It works fine but the resulting apps I create are for 64bit OS only .

My question is , will it be easy for me to recompile my app afterwards for 32 bit ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just complile qt and your app for x86.